# Styling GeoJSON polygons with hatch fill in MapFish Print

Tags: geojson, style, sld, json, mapfish-print

I am working with MapFish Print (v3.23.1) and have a mix of layers for a map, some from GeoServer and some local GeoJSON files. I have GeoJSON polygons that I would like to apply a hatch pattern to, but I can't find a way to do this. I am using the MapFish JSON Style Version 2, and tried to use the graphicName property with the value set to shape://backslash (I tried both inside and outside of brackets as this could be an ECQL expression) without luck. No errors, just doesn't apply. According to the [documentation](https://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/styles.html) it looks as though that style may only apply to point geometry, which I don't quite understand. The documentation also mentions that SLD formatting is supported, but I can't figure out how to set that up in the request JSON. I tried setting style property equal to file://style.sld, and also to the SLD as a string; it ignores the file reference, and gives syntax error on the SLD string. I am pasting the portion of my JSON file below that includes the GeoJSON properties. Does anyone if it is possible to apply a hatch style to the polygons and if so how to do it?

```
"layers": [
                {
                    "type": "geojson",
                    "geoJson": "file://parcels_wind.geojson",
                    "style": {
                        "version": 2,
                        "*": {
                            "symbolizers": [
                                {
                                    "type": "polygon",
                                    "fillColor": "#8400a8",
                                    "fillOpacity": 0.1,
                                    "strokeColor": "#8400a8",
                                    "strokeOpacity": 1,
                                    "strokeWidth": 3,
                                    "graphicName": "shape://backslash"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fontColor": "#000000",
                                    "label": "[owner_id]",
                                    "labelAlign": "cm",
                                    "goodnessOfFit": 0.1,
                                    "spaceAround": 10,
                                    "fontFamily": "Arial Narrow",
                                    "fontSize": "8px",
                                    "fontStyle": "normal",
                                    "fontWeight": "bold",
                                    "haloColor": "#ffff00",
                                    "haloOpacity": 1,
                                    "haloRadius": 4
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/issues/899

Storing the SLD file with other template files and referencing the file location for the style property is what worked for me.